# ExtJS Window is undefined after hiding

Tags: extjs, window

I have a window which is created at the page load and registered in the component manager. 
The window has closeAction: 'hide' set but when I try to reopen it, I get an error that the window is undefined. Using ExtJs 3.4

```
#Initial creation of the window
var comWin = new UserSelectionDialog();
Ext.ComponentMgr.register(comWin);

#Window Class/Config
UserSelectionDialog = Ext.extend(Ext.Window, {
id: 'comWin',
title: 'User Selection',
width: 700,
height: 300,   
autoScroll: true,
maximizable: true,
closeAction: 'hide'...


#call to retrieve window
function getCom(){

var comWin = Ext.getCmp('comWin');
alert(comWin.title);
    comWin.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is covered in the window docs, by default, when you hit close it destroys the window.

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.Window-cfg-closeAction

Comment: I figured this out. One of my functions was calling this.close() instead of this.hide()

Comment: Right, my answer correct, whether you close it via the UI it just calls close().